how to create a stacked card with animation in flutter
I am trying to make this animation by using stack

the problem is when the card in the back animate and suppose to appears on top of the others it stays in the back
I have done some search and couldn't find anything that can be used to make animation when changing the stacked elements
any help will be appreciated.
class CardAnimationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CardAnimationScreenState createState() => _CardAnimationScreenState();
}

class _CardAnimationScreenState extends State<CardAnimationScreen> {
  // To manage the card states (0 for card 1, 1 for card 2, 2 for card 3)
  List<int> cardOrder = [0, 1, 2];
  bool isAnimating = false;

  void animateCards() {
    if (isAnimating) return;

    setState(() {
      isAnimating = true;
    });
    // Start the animation
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 300), () {
      setState(() {
        // Rotate the order of cards (the first becomes last)
        cardOrder.insert(0, cardOrder.removeLast());
        isAnimating = false;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Card Animation')),
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          children: [
            _buildAnimatedCard(0, cardOrder.indexOf(0)), // Card 1
            _buildAnimatedCard(1, cardOrder.indexOf(1)), // Card 2
            _buildAnimatedCard(2, cardOrder.indexOf(2)), // Card 3 (on top)
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: animateCards,
        child: Icon(Icons.play_arrow),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildAnimatedCard(int cardIndex, int positionIndex) {
    // Defining positions for the cards
    final List<Alignment> positions = [
      Alignment(-0.8, 0.2), // Back-left position (Card 1)
      Alignment(0.8, 0.2), // Back-right position (Card 2)
      Alignment(0, -0.3), // Top position (Card 3)
    ];

    return AnimatedAlign(
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      alignment: positions[positionIndex],
      child: Container(
        width: 150,
        height: 200,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: _getCardColor(cardIndex),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black26,
              blurRadius: 10,
              spreadRadius: 2,
              offset: Offset(2, 4),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Color _getCardColor(int cardIndex) {
    // Assign colors based on card index
    switch (cardIndex) {
      case 0:
        return Colors.redAccent;
      case 1:
        return Colors.greenAccent;
      case 2:
        return Colors.blueAccent;
      default:
        return Colors.grey;
    }
  }
}


You can use one of the existing flutter packages in pub.dev such as stacked_card_carousel package.
Also you can check the following link for more packages regarding this UI.

the problem is that I need to made the rotation animation as I have three cards
and they will keep rotating with one on top and two are behind it
